Question mark for unfinished question?
I am wondering if using a question mark at the end of the following sentence is acceptable:

Is there any— I mean?

Or should an ellipsis be used:

Is there any— I mean...

The words in the sentence must not be changed.

Your question asks how to punctuate a question that is left unfinished. Here are the relevant conventions:

If an utterance is left unfinished and trails off into silence, you add an ellipsis at the end:

"But I thought he was..."


If an utterance is interrupted and breaks off abruptly, you add an em dash at the end:

"But I'm trying to explain that I—"


If an utterance is a question, this is identified by a question mark:

"How are you?"


When a question trails off, the ellipsis and question are combined:

"Could you...?"


When a question breaks off abruptly, the em dash and question mark are combined:

"Wha—?"




How your example needs to be punctuated depends on whether the two parts trail off or break off abruptly and whether the second part is pronounced in a questioning tone or not. This gives us the following eight options:

Is there any...? I mean...
Is there any...? I mean—
Is there any—? I mean...
Is there any—? I mean—
Is there any...? I mean...?
Is there any...? I mean—?
Is there any—? I mean...?
Is there any—? I mean—?

If the second part trails off or breaks off, the following is false:

* I mean?


Thanks for your input.  The "I mean" is sort of asking a question. In the context, it is to try to convey: "I mean [can anything be done]?  I hadn't realized that a question mark could be used after an em dash.

@Cedar If "I mean" is uttered in a questioning tone, just add a question mark after it: "Is there any...? I mean...?" To me, that feels strange, because I cannot think of a question that begins with "I mean", but if you can, do so. Note: Something like "I mean, is there any milk left?" is actually two clauses, a statement ("I mean") and a question ("Is there any milk left"), and the first clause isn't intonated as a question but as a statement.

@Cedar I see. Try and say that aloud. I'm convinced you will realize that the first and last are intonated as questions, while the middle "I mean" has a different intonation. I therefore still think that there shouldn't be a question mark after "I mean..." But as I said, if you perceive it as a question, simply write "I mean...?", that is, use both ellipsis and question mark. —— Does all of this taken together answer your question?

Thanks again for your thoughts.  In the context, if the sentence did not contain an ellipsis or em dash, it would read something like: "Is there any way,  I mean, can anything be done?" Or else as two sentences: "Is there any way something can be done?  I mean, is it possible?"  The sentence, or sentences, are from an audio transcription. I have been trying the say it aloud approach, but may need to listen to the audio again. I just don't have access to it at the moment.  It seemed as though the "I mean" was said in a questioning tone, but I also get what you are saying.

@ Ben.  I deleted one of my comments because I needed to edit it but it was outside the  5 minute editing window. Sorry about that.

In the example sentence in your comment above, "I mean, is there any milk left?" is the "I mean" used as filler, where it can basically be removed and the meaning of the sentence is not changed?  If so, could my sentence read, "Is there any, I mean . . . ?  where the meaning of the sentence would be "Is there any . . .?" and the "I mean" is a filler?  Or would there need to be an ellipsis instead of a comma between "any" and "I mean"?

@Cedar "Is there any" is obviously unfinished, so you need to signify that it either trails off ("...") or breaks off ("—"). A comma is wrong after an ellpsis or em-dash. "I mean" signifies that what follows is a clarification or correction of the preceding part of the speech. In your case, the attempt at clarifying or correcting is aborted ("I mean...").

Wikipedia has a page titled: "Hedge (linguistics)" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics), where the phrase "I mean" is said to be used as a hedge "when expectations are not met or when people want to avoid answering a question." That is how the "I mean" seems to be used in this case. The speaker is trying to ask a question about a very difficult subject and is trying to hedge, which is why the question being asked is not finished.  The "I mean" is not to clarify or correct what precedes it in this case.

@Cedar And a hedge isn't a question either, so should not take a question mark.

OK.  Thank you.  I am still not sure if the sentence could be punctuated as one sentence, or would need to be two sentences (or partial sentences).  I have seen where sometimes, even though only part of a sentence contains a question, the whole sentence ends with a question mark.  So I wonder if the the sentence could be punctuated: "Is there any . . . I mean . . .? That is the only remaining question I have.

@Cedar Yes, you can.
